# How to limit the keys of a TypeScript type?

Tags: typescript

I would like to do:

```
type PossibleKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

... and now I would like to create a type which the key has to be necessarily one of the above. Like:

```
type MyType = {
 a: number;
 b: string;
 c: boolean;
 d: {} // <--- I want it not to be allowed because `d` does not extend `PossibleKeys`
}
```

How would you do that?

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: not sure what you're asking here. Do you want to restrict the type definition or create a type that restricts instances based on `PossibleKeys`.

Comment: `type MyType = Record<PossibleKeys, unknown>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own type validator, using the pattern `T extends (Condition ? unknown : never)`

```
type ValidateKeys<
    K,
    T extends ([keyof T] extends [K] ? [K] extends [keyof T] ? unknown : never : never)
> = T

type PossibleKeys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type MyType = ValidateKeys<PossibleKeys, {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: boolean;
}>
```

Comment: Amazing! FWIW this also works without the tuple syntax i.e.,

`T extends keyof T extends K ? (K extends keyof T ? unknown : never) : never`